# RxJava is event driven. Shouldn't it be message driven?

Tags: rx-java, reactive

Reactive manifesto clearly defines a reactive system as message driven system and it clearly differentiates a message driven system from an event driven system

See glossary http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/glossary#Message-Driven

Yet RxJava and other reactive systems define themselves as event driven systems.

Observer (recipient) is attached to the Observable (event source) which as per reactive manifesto seems to be a big no no

how come?

what am i missing?

Comment: By the way, where did you find that RxJava is *event driven*?

Comment: RxJava is a Java VM implementation of ReactiveX (Reactive Extensions): a library for composing asynchronous and event-based programs by using observable sequences.

Comment: event-based not same as event-driven?  
manifesto - In a message-driven system addressable recipients await the arrival of messages and react to them, otherwise lying dormant. In an event-driven system notification listeners are attached to the sources of events such that they are invoked when the event is emitted.  
In RxJavaObserver(listener) is attached to Observable(event source).  Further messages are not explicitly defined

Answer (score 3):

I think the difference between *message driven* and *event driven* is rather conceptual than practical. The implementations of both would be very similar. Many developers use these terms interchangeably.

Comment: saying that the difference is conceptual rather than practical seems like a polite way of saying just ignore the manifesto. As far as implementation is concerned the manifesto clearly thinks that they are implemented differently.

Comment: @satgurusrivastava RxJava is most definitely *reactive*, and I would say that it is rather *message driven* than *event driven*. Many developers just do not pay so much attention to wording once they understand the principle.